# Classic asp - Is there a way to see the relationships (an " <!--#include map") between asp scripts?

Tags: asp-classic, include, dreamweaver

I have a website with many classic asp scripts which are included one inside the other using the `<!--#include` statement.

When I want to find the server side code for something in the website, it's very hard to find which asp file actually handles it...

Is there some tool, extension or something that I can do to view/visualize these connections, i.e. see which asp file is included inside which? "asp site map" or something?

BTW the website has aspx (webforms) pages as well.

Thanks.

**Edit - comment to comment **

I installed Dreamweaver trial but in the "related files" toolbar I can only see one level of asp "includes":

[image]

In this case, functions.asp has many includes inside it, and is also included in other files.

How can I see the "nested" includes?

I also switched "Discover dynamically related files" to "automatically" in Preferences, with no avail. As I understand, this feature is what I'm looking for?

Comment: What IDE are you using (if any)?

Comment: Paul - I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I use Dreamweaver. This shows include files in the order they appear. Not a map but certainly I have found most effective for purpose.